# Chromedriver keeps losing connection right after the start of the selenium test

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, nunit

I have a selenium test for a single page web application. When I start the test it starts chrome, navigates to the desired URL and maximises the browser. But that is pretty much it. Right after these steps it just shows the page of the desired URL until the test fails because of a timeout:

```
The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:59833/session/9b0d7ae349643a68d86bf8ce2ef419ee/element/18f73f99-48e6-4fa9-81a8-d77d3d6ff80c/click timed out after 60 seconds.
  ----> System.Net.WebException : The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.

Call stack:
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at MyTest.Pages.Login..ctor() in D:\Path\To\Test\Project\Pages\Login.cs:line 30
   at TearDown.SetUp()
```

It seems to me that only specific actions produce this problem. E.g. if I put my cursor over the page body and click in there my test will run until a certain test case and then lose connection even if all test cases which ran before passed the exact same code for reloading the side.

The same exact behavior occurs when I initialize the chromedriver with the `"--headless"` option.

I already had the same exact problem some weeks ago but the genuis "fix" seemed to be to start the test and do not touch anything (don't move the mouse, don't press any key on the keyboard) until it was done. This does not work anymore and is clearly no final solution as the test should automatically run on a build server.

I have no idea what else to do. Here is what I have tried already:

- Advise the WebDriver to click the "body" element on the page:
  `Driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).Click();`
- Execute some JavaScript to focus the browser `((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.focus();");`
- Initializes the WebDriver with different arguments like `"--no-sandbox"`, `"--disable-gpu"`, `"ignore-certificate-errors"`, `"--headless"`

Has anyone had the same problem or any idea of how to fix this?

If more of my code is required, please let me know.

***EDIT***

The problems occurs with the following code:

```
SharedResources.Resources.DefaultTimeout = General.TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS;
SharedResources.Resources.ScreenShotTaken += OnScreenshotTaken;

// login to the web app to invoke the web api which takes a second to initialize on first use. This is where the problem actually occurs
Login().DoLoginByClickLoginButton(SharedResources.Resources.AdminUser.Username, SharedResources.Resources.AdminUser.Password);
Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

Constructor of `Login` looks like this:

```
public Login()
{
    Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(General.MAIN_URL);
    Driver.Navigate().Refresh();
    Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    Toolbox.AwaitElementVisible(By.Id(BUTTON_LOGIN_ID), General.TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    Driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).Click(); // This line is the one mentioned in the call stack
}
```

***HOW I SET UP THE WEBDRIVER***

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--window-size=1920,1200");
chromeOptions.UnhandledPromptBehavior = UnhandledPromptBehavior.Accept;

this.WebDriver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WebDrivers")), chromeOptions);
```

Comment: Could you show the code in which this error is reproduced?

Comment: This issue happening because existing process of chromedriver running in background. Please kill all chromedriver process from the system (Server or local machine) where are you running test cases. Additionally show me how you have set up chrome driver instance.

Comment: I have made another edit where you can see how I set up my WebDriver. When the tests are run there is no other chromedriver.exe running in the taskmanager. Just for test purposes I have also closed all other "normal" instances of chrome. It made no difference.

Comment: Are you passing chromedriver binaries path? is it path Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WebDrivers"))

Comment: Yes the path to the binaries is stored on the environment variable "WebDrivers" which I give to the constructor of ChromeDriver

Comment: Have you tried to remove the click on the `<body>` tag in the `Login` constructor?

Comment: Yes I have also tried it without this line. No change.

Comment: Which version of Chrome and ChromeDriver are you using? The major version numbers need to match.

Comment: The version of my ChromeDriver is 79.0.3945.3600 and the one of chrome is 79.0.3945.130

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is dealing with the same problem, I have found the solution in downgrading the ChromeDriver all the way back to 2.40.0 (almost 20 versions below the version I was using before which was 79.0.3945.3600)

Of course this is not the best solution but I can at least run my tests without any problems now.